# Guardar información entre activities en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: android, arraylist, activity

Resulta que tengo un ArrayList que mediante un activityResult está obteniendo más datos, sin embargo, cuando entro a un elemento de la lista y vuelvo a la actividad, el ArrayList se destruye y se vuelve a crear... ¿Cómo puedo lograr que en tiempo de ejecución el ArrayList no pierda su valor al cambiar de activity?

```
 private ArrayList<Contacto>listaContactos;
 private ListView lvContactos;
```

**ACTIVITY RESULT**

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if((requestCode == requestCode) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)){
            Gson json = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Contacto>>(){}.getType();
            listaContactos =  json.fromJson(data.getDataString(),listType);
            llenarLista();
        }
    }
```

**METODO LLENAR LISTA**

```
 private void llenarLista(){
        AdaptadorContacto adaptador = new AdaptadorContacto(this);
        lvContactos.setAdapter(adaptador);
    }
```

**CAMBIO DE ACTIVITY**

```
 lvContactos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder  =  new AlertDialog.Builder(Principal.this);
                builder.setMessage("¿Deseas ver la información de "+listaContactos.get(position).getNickname()+"?").setTitle("Importante").setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Gson json = new Gson();
                            String contacto = json.toJson(listaContactos.get(position));
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InfoContacto.class);
                            i.putExtra("contacto",contacto);
                            startActivity(i);
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Seguro que se vacía listaContacto? No debería puesto que no cierras la actividad.

Comment: En el único lugar que cierro es en cuando envío el activity result nuevamente, es decir:

       contactos.add(c);
       Gson json = new Gson();
       String lista = json.toJson(contactos);
       Intent data = new Intent();
       data.setData(Uri.parse(lista));
       setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
       finish();

Comment: Una posible solución seria tener una clase con variables globales e ir guardando ahí el arraylist que quieres que se cargue

Comment: para guardar resultados si no recuerdo mal deberias usar Sharedpreferences si no recuerdo mal :)

Comment: Si pero cierras la actividad nueva si no me equivoco, con lo cual la "vieja" que mantienes abierta debería guardar los datos. Como dice @juank una posibilidad es guardarlo en las SharedPreferences pero como te digo, si no cierras la actividad ni haces nada raro, debería guardarte los valores.

Comment: Asegurate de no estar pisando la listaContactos en el onResume y de estar cerrando bien la Activity de InfoContacto con un finish() pero como digo @PabloSimonDiEstefano no deberia perderse si no haces nada raro

Comment: Si el error no está en un seteo desde otro lado de la app, prueba a inicializar el ArrayList en el onResume() así, al volver a la activity, recuperamos el dato que estaba guardado.